# Add ipad interface to iphone app

Tags: ios

I have been watching some of the solutions for this problem. There's any solution that not implies changing the code? I have seen solutions like put an if/else with the device type every time I load a ViewController. Theres no a way with xcode that this step is automaticaly done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better method to include my iPad Xib in my project. I only have to add ~iPad at the end of the name of my xib. If I have myxib.xib I create a new xib named myxib~iPad.xib and when I run it on my ipad it takes automatically the correct file!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using storyboards in the info.plist you can choose by configuration each storyboard, one for iPad and other for iPhone/iPod touch

If you are using `xibs` you'l need to change it programmatically using ifs and elses